# How to return an error from TComObjectFactory.CreateComObject(const Controller: IUnknown): TComObject

Tags: delphi, com

I have a custom COM server implementation. The server is using a TComObjectFactory to create the COM objects that are used for client connections.

I had written it like this:

```
function TPsOPCProviderClientFactory.CreateComObject(const Controller:
    IUnknown): TComObject;
begin
  FStartupCompleteEvent.WaitFor(INFINITE);
  if Provider.State = OPC_STATUS_SUSPENDED then // Server already shutdown
    raise EAbort.Create('Server shut down.');
  Result := inherited CreateComObject(Controller);
  (Result as TPsOPCProviderClient).Provider := Provider;
end;
```

The FStartupCompleteEvent is used to ensure that the application is ready before the first connection is let through and the Provider.State is used to disable client connections when the server is going to shut down.

Now it appears that this is not the proper way to cancel the object creation: if the exception is raised it will make a message dialog with "DAX Error" popup on the screen and the client may crash.

What is the correct way to make the object creation fail - or is it compulsory to always succeed?

The code is used in a component framework that is available for all Delphi/C++Builder versions since Delphi 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't let any exception escape from your [`DllGetClassObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680760%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) COM entry point.
Instead you should trap this exception and return an appropriate `HResult` value (possibly `E_UNEXPECTED`).

It could look similar to this:

```
function DllGetClassObject(const CLSID, IID: TGUID; var Obj): HResult;
begin
  try
    Result := ComServ.DllGetClassObject(CLSID, IID, Obj);
  except
    Pointer(Obj) := nil;
    Result := E_UNEXPECTED;
  end;
end;
```

Edit: Alternatively, it would be simpler to modify your `CreateComObject` method to return nil instead of raising an exception. The default `DllGetClassObject` implementation in `ComServ` will return `CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE` in that case.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose my main issue was that should I just return nil. I think this answers it.

Comment: This is not the issue, there are no exceptions escaped. The RTL already catches exceptions raised in CreateComObject and returns `E_UNEXPECTED`. And returning nil will cause an AV when RTL tries to retrieve the com interface on the object. My guess is it's the clients that don't handle the fail gracefully.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Which version of Delphi are you talking about and where does RTL catch exceptions raised in CreateComObject? And how does returning nil cause A/V? Thanks.

Comment: @TOndrej - I looked at the source of XE2, CreateComObject is called by CreateInstanceLic in an overriden factory.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Thank you! I'll check it later when I have some time.